# PDO update row value in foreach loop

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I created a table, inside a foreach loop displaying in the table all the records. Then I included a SQL update with the select and update one array value. When I select different value, the loop updates all the records in the table and NOT only one selected to be updated. I was all day struggling with it, please help me.

If foreach is a wrong way, I would highly appreciate your suggestions of how to display a table that would display records and permit updates for each array.

```
<?php
            foreach ($stmt as $key => $row)
            {

                $newcustomerid = htmlentities($row['customer_id']);

                echo '<tr><td>' . htmlentities($row['customer_company']) . '</td>';
                echo '<td> id:' . $newcustomerid . 'key: ' . $key .'</td>';
                echo '<td>' . htmlentities($row['customer_email']) . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . htmlentities($row['customer_phone']) . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . htmlentities($row['customer_country']) . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . htmlentities($row['customer_city']) . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . htmlentities($row['customer_segment']) . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . htmlentities($row['customer_updated']) . '</td>';
                $customer_status = htmlentities($row['customer_status']);

                if(isset($_POST['Submitbb'])){ //check if form was submitted
                $input = $_POST['Submitbb']; //get input text

                    $stmtUpdateStatus = $conn->prepare("UPDATE user_customers SET `customer_status` = :customer_status WHERE `customer_id` = :customer_id");
                    $stmtUpdateStatus->execute(array(':customer_status' => $input, ':customer_id' => $row['customer_id']));
                }

                echo '<td>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <select name="Submitbb" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                            <option> - ' . $customer_status . ' - </option>
                            <option>Susisiekti</option>
                            <option>Priminimas 1</option>
                            <option>Priminimas 2</option>
                            <option>Paskambinti</option>
                            <option>Netinkamas klientas</option>
                            </select>
                    </form>
                </td>';


                echo '<td>' . 'Išsaugoti' . '</td></tr>';

            }



        ?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hidden input to capture the row in the database you wish to update

```
 echo '<td>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <input name="customer_id" type="hidden" value="'.$newcustomerid.'"/>  <!-- hidden -->
                    <select name="Submitbb" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                        <option> - ' . $customer_status . ' - </option>
                        <option>Susisiekti</option>
                        <option>Priminimas 1</option>
                        <option>Priminimas 2</option>
                        <option>Paskambinti</option>
                        <option>Netinkamas klientas</option>
                        </select>
                </form>
            </td>';
```

Then compare it when the form is posted

```
            if(isset($_POST['Submitbb'])){ //check if form was submitted
            $input = $_POST['Submitbb']; //get input text
            $customer_id =  $_POST['customer_id']; // get the posted customer ID
            if($row['customer_id'] == $customer_id){

                    $stmtUpdateStatus = $conn->prepare("UPDATE user_customers SET `customer_status` = :customer_status WHERE `customer_id` = :customer_id");
                    $stmtUpdateStatus->execute(array(':customer_status' => $input, ':customer_id' => $customer_id)); 
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you ! But..it says: "Undefined index: customer_id" in the third line of the second code block that you posted..

Comment: Hey, take a new copy of both blocks i've made several edits, including one to fix that error

Comment: Thank you so much, but unfortunately it is not submitting now. I tested it several times, no update is made in the database. :/ @andrew

Comment: oh, i think i know why, i didn't notice you were using single quotes, ive changed it like this `<input name="customer_id" type="hidden" value="'.$newcustomerid.'"/>` see the edit

Comment: No error, nothing, but the data is not submitting. I will keep testing it and trying to found out why .. :/

Comment: ok, sorry, some things you can check, right click on the `<select name="Submitbb"...` in your browser and inspect element check the hidden input beside it and see the value is set to the customer id also goto your browser network tab and view the submitted data when you submit the form

Comment: It works now, that name is like that on purpose, to not be the same as other Submits, but I finally works what you sent me, thank you so much for helping me out, I really appreciate it so much !!!